# Check if In-App Purchase can be made before displaying the button

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm implementing In-App purchases in an XCode project, and everything works fine except for one error. When the user isn't connected to the internet and he clicks a purchase button, the app crashes. I believe this happens because the in-app purchases haven't been fetched from iTunes and clicking the button can't run the purchase process. This crash also happens when the user clicks the button on the first second that the shop screen loads, because – I think – some time is needed to fetch (or request) the products. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       ...
    fetchAvailableProducts()
}

func fetchAvailableProducts()  {

    // Put here your IAP Products ID's
    let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects:
        productID100,
        productID250,
        productID500,
        productIDRemoveAds,
        productIDUnlockAll)

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
    productsRequest.delegate = self
    productsRequest.start()

}
```

I'm basing my code on [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/in-app-purchase-tutorial-with-swift-3-ios-sdk--cms-27595).

Is there a way to change my code to make it "crash-proof", so that it first checks if the products can be bought to let you use the button?

Comment: Provide the details of the crash. It sounds like you aren't using the successful retrieval of products to enable your ui

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm doing everything like the linked tutorial.

Comment: Right, so that tutorial code is written as a minimal example; it doesn't check to see if the products have been retrieved before allowing an attempted purchase; so you will get an array bounds exception. You should enable your purchase UI in the product request delegate method

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, this is exactly what I want to do. How could I code this?

Comment: You would hide or disable your purchase UI initially and then show/enable it in `SKProductRequest(didReceive:)`

Answer (score 0):

I use SwiftyStorkeKit ( https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit ) , which uses a completion handler to fill in the products (will save you from reinventing the wheel as well - and is a great resource to learn from)

As for checking network connection, I use Apple's Reachability ( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html ). Here is the relevant parts of an implementation. It also check in situations where the app loses focus. You can also use the network check before any store operation.

```
class vcon: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var noConnectionView: UIView!

    func isNetworkAvailable() -> Bool {
    //quick test if network is available
        var netTest:Reachability? = Reachability(hostName: "apple.com")!
        if netTest?.currentReachabilityStatus == .notReachable {
            netTest = nil
            return false
        }
        netTest = nil
        return true
    }

    func displayNoNetworkView() {
    //this example pulls from a storyboard to a view I have in front of everything else at all times, and shows the view to block everything else if the network isnt available

        let ncvc = UIStoryboard(name: "HelpPrefsInfo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "noNetworkVC") as! noNetworkVC
        ncvc.view.frame = noConnectionView.bounds
        ncvc.view.backgroundColor = color03
        ncvc.no_connection_imageView.tintColor = color01
        ncvc.noInternetConnection_label.textColor = color01
        noConnectionView.addSubview(ncvc.view)
    }

    func hideDataIfNoConnection() {
//the actual code that displays the no net connection view
        if !isNetworkAvailable() {
            if noConnectionView.isHidden == true {
                noConnectionView.alpha = 0
                noConnectionView.isHidden = false
                self.iapObjects = []
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.50, animations: {
                    self.noConnectionView.alpha = 1
                }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
                });
            }
        } else {
            if noConnectionView.isHidden == false {
                self.collection_view.reloadData()
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.50, animations: {
                    self.noConnectionView.alpha = 0
                }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
                    self.noConnectionView.isHidden = true
                    self.loadIAPData()
                });
            }
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

        displayNoNetworkView()

        loadIAPData()

    }

    func loadIAPData() {
load the data if the network is available

        if isNetworkAvailable() {

           helper.requestProductsWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: { (success, products) -> Void in
                if success {
                    self.iapObjects = products!
                    self.collection_view.reloadData()
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Cannot retrieve products list right now.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }

   func willEnterForeground() {
        hideDataIfNoConnection()
    }

}

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        hideDataIfNoConnection()

    }
```